# How to get value from html table <tr>?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that need to validate the table header name. For example, it wont allow user to click a button if the HTML consist a header name `Group1`. So my question is how can I find the table header name `Group1` in the `<tr>` using Javascript?

Full HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tableid">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Device</th>
         <th>Serial</th>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Groups</th>
         <th>Device</th>
         <td>Group1</td>
         <td>Group2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>TY83-FPSX-C3WS</td>
         <td>xxx1</td>
         <td>test1</td>
         <td>John</td>
         <td> Driver</td>
         <td>DKFU-V7ZE-RD9R</td>
         <td>
            <div class="col" classname="col">
               <select name="group1" id="groupId">
                  <option>Null</option>
                  <option value="IT">IT</option>
                  <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
                  <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="col" classname="col">
               <select name="group1" id="groupId">
                  <option>Null</option>
                  <option value="IT">IT</option>
                  <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
                  <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>4SB9-NR2D-742E</td>
         <td>xxx2</td>
         <td>test2</td>
         <td>Cena</td>
         <td>Telesales</td>
         <td>DqwdKFU-VqwdZE-RD9R</td>
         <td>
            <div class="col" classname="col">
               <select name="group1" id="groupId">
                  <option>Null</option>
                  <option value="IT">IT</option>
                  <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
                  <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
            <div class="col" classname="col">
               <select name="group1" id="groupId">
                  <option>Null</option>
                  <option value="IT">IT</option>
                  <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
                  <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you alter the markup generated? That table is not semantically correct - the header should be in a `<thead>`, not part of the `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First if there is no specific reason to use `td` tag like this (in 1st `tr` tag) then it can be used in next `tr` tag . Below solution is applicable on present use of tag but with some changes .

You can loop through all `th` tag and match the `innerHTML` with required condition, if that matched get the `i` value (which is the tag having that value).

Using `i` value print the output

```js
function func() {
  var trTag = document.querySelector("tr");
  var thTag = trTag.querySelectorAll("th");
  for (let i = 0; i < thTag.length; i++) {
    if (thTag[i].innerHTML === "Group1")
      var current = i;
  }

  document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = thTag[current].innerHTML;
  thTag[current].style.backgroundColor = "red"

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tableid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Device</th>
      <th>Serial</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Groups</th>
      <th>Device</th>
      <th>Group1</th>
      <th>Group2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TY83-FPSX-C3WS</td>
      <td>xxx1</td>
      <td>test1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td> Driver</td>
      <td>DKFU-V7ZE-RD9R</td>
      <td>
        <div class="col" classname="col">
          <select name="group1" id="groupId">
            <option>Null</option>
            <option value="IT">IT</option>
            <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
            <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col" classname="col">
          <select name="group1" id="groupId">
            <option>Null</option>
            <option value="IT">IT</option>
            <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
            <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4SB9-NR2D-742E</td>
      <td>xxx2</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>Cena</td>
      <td>Telesales</td>
      <td>DqwdKFU-VqwdZE-RD9R</td>
      <td>
        <div class="col" classname="col">
          <select name="group1" id="groupId">
            <option>Null</option>
            <option value="IT">IT</option>
            <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
            <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col" classname="col">
          <select name="group1" id="groupId">
            <option>Null</option>
            <option value="IT">IT</option>
            <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
            <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="func()">Click</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is no specific reason for using td in Group1 and Group2 then this can be modified to:

Original HTML :

```
 <tr>
     <th>Device</th>
     <th>Serial</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Groups</th>
     <th>Device</th>
     <td>Group1</td>
     <td>Group2</td>
  </tr>
```

Modified HTML :

```
  <tr>
     <th>Device</th>
     <th>Serial</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Groups</th>
     <th>Device</th>
     <th>Group1</th>
     <th>Group2</th>
  </tr>
```

And the following code works:

```
$("#tableid").on('click', 'td', function(e) {
   //debug statement to check if it entered the function
   console.log("debug: in function working") 

  // to get the column index of the cell clicked
  var index = $(this).index();

  // debug statement to check the index
  console.log(index); 

  // get the table
  var table = $(this).closest('table'); 

  // get the header name.
  var header = table.find('tr th').eq(index).text();
 
 //debug statement to check header name
 console.log(header); 

 //check if the header is group 1 then pop alert not to click button
  if(header == "Group1")
    alert("you cannot click button");  
});
```

Another thing you could do if the td is important is that you can put all header elements in tr with a class="header_validate" for example and change the line:

`var header = table.find('tr th').eq(index).text();`

with

`var header = table.find('tr .header_validate').eq(index).text();`